# Er hustet wie [???]

Tags: word-choice

Gibt es im deutschen solchen Ausdruck, in der Bedeutung, dass jemand sehr stark hustet?

> Er hustet wie Teufel/Bergarbeiter. // sagt man?

Comment: Er hustset wie ein Rasenmäher.

Comment: *… wie ein HB-Männchen.* – Nee, das war was anderes.

Comment: https://www.pferde-daempfigkeit.de/symptome-und-diagnose.html  Aber wer weiss denn heutzutage noch, wie ein Pferd hustet? Oder was ein Traktor ist?  „ Er hustet wie ein alter VW-Bus!“  Da wird auch kaum jemand noch wissen, was das heissen könnte. Auf daß man auch heute noch husten kann wie ein Roß, würde ich vorschlagen: Er hustet wie die Müllabfuhr! (Da wird man jedenfalls auch aus dem Schlaf gerissen.

Comment: Ich hatte mal sogar einen Husten wie ein Deux-Chevaux! https://www.google.com/search?q=deux+chevaux&rlz=1C9BKJA_enCH812CH813&oq=deux+chevaux&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.10346j0j9&hl=de&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=GD0OsVhnt6v4QM:

Comment: Wie *Huperts*, scheinbar ein Personenname der generisch verstärkend eingesetzt wird, wohl ähnlich wie *Hulle* unten, das ich aber nicht kenne (Ableitung von *Hölle*, *like hell*? *Frau Holle*, bzgl. Wind und Wetter?).

Comment: @Albrecht: aber *Husten wie eine Ente* klingt irgendwie nicht richtig. <g>

Answer (score 7):

> Er hustet sich die Lunge aus dem Leib.

wäre das, was dem meiner Meinung nach am nächsten kommt.

Comment: Ja, aber das ist die Beschreibung einer Person, die in dem Moment gerade hustet. Man würde das eher nicht als generelle Beschreibung verwenden, oder?

Answer (score 1):

Das ist regional unterschiedlich.

*Er hustet wie Teufel.* ist durchaus geläufig aber eben nicht überall. In Berlin wäre zum Beispiel auch ein Ausdruck wie *Er hustet wie Hulle.* nicht ungewöhnlich. Frag mich bitte nicht, was *Hulle* heißt. Ich weiß es nicht, habe das aber schon häufig von Leuten aus Berlin und Umgebung gehört. *Wie Hulle* hat dabei immer die Bedeutung von *sehr stark*.

Auch *Er hustet wie verrückt.* ist umgangssprachlich gebräuchlich.

*Er hustet wie Bergarbeiter.* könnte mein neuer Favorit werden. Das habe ich noch nie gehört, halte es aber als Redensart im mittleren Westen für durchaus denkbar, wobei es dann möglicherweise eher heißt, *er hustet wie **ein** Bergarbeiter*.

Answer (score 1):

Es hiess früher:

> Er hustet wie ein Roß.

https://www.pferde-daempfigkeit.de/symptome-und-diagnose.html

Aber nach der Industrialisierung der Landwirtschaft müsste es heissen:

> Er hustet wie ein Traktor.

Und in der Stadt:

> Er hustet wie die Müllabfuhr!

Comment: Als Beleg für das hustende Pferd/Roß eignen sich besser wenn dann [dies](https://books.google.de/books?id=mZxbAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA81&dq=%22er+hustet+wie+ein+d%C3%A4mpfiges+ross%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEsN6Mn7HgAhV06KYKHbD4CwAQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22er%20hustet%20wie%20ein%20d%C3%A4mpfiges%20ross%22&f=false) oder [dies](http://doczz.com.br/doc/1266248/stende-10-novembris---latvie%C5%A1u-valodas-instit%C5%ABts) . Die anderen beiden sind nur persönliche, modernisierte Weiterentwicklungen die heute erfunden wurden, oder? Halte ich für nicht so hilfreich, da nach etablierten Ausdrücken gefragt wurde.

Comment: "Er keucht wie ein altes Pferd" 1798, [Phraseologia Anglo-Germanica](https://books.google.de/books?id=d-ARAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq="er+keucht+wie+ein"&source=bl&ots=vxQK39rScj&sig=ACfU3U0BIcDsIXokPSC5jVRWuyQsd0iO9g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFkpqRpbHgAhUQNOwKHaGBCloQ6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q="er%20keucht%20wie%20ein"&f=false). Vgl. *Keuchhusten*. Meine Mutter sagte *bellen*, entsprechend findet sich *keuchen wie ein Hund*, *husten wie ein bellender Hund*.

Comment: ... es heisst überhaut nichts, dass nach einem etablierten Ausdruck gesucht wird. Wie der Teufel hustet, kann kein Mensch sagen. Aber es ist ganz allgemein bekannt, dass  ein Pferd abgetan muss, wenn es hustet.  Als ich heute in einer Runde diese Frage stellte, kam prompt die Antwort: "wie ein Pferd!" unter Pferde husten zeigt Google immerhin 18000 Einträge an. Wenn  ihr darüber nicht Bescheid wisst, heisst das nicht, dass andere Antworten falsche sind. Keuchen ist etwas ganz anderes als husten. Und dass Hunde bellen, ist offensichtlich bis zu euch durchgedrungen.

Comment: 1. Die Frage lautet: "Gibt es im Deutschen einen Ausdruck" und nicht "Wie könnte ein Ausdruck im Deutschen lauten". 2. Dass es den Ausdruck "Husten wie ein Pferd" gibt wird nicht bezweifelt. Aber die Existenz des Ausdrucks belegen zu wollen indem man darauf hinweist, dass Pferde allgemein husten können oder es eine Pferdehustenkrankheit gibt bringt nichts. Vor allem, wenn es andere Textstellen gibt in denen genau der Ausdruck entsprechend der Frage verwendet wird. 3. Wie der Teufel etwas macht muss man nicht wissen, denn a) [Redensart](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redensart) und b) etabliert

Comment: Pferdehusten sollte immer ernst genommen werden

Hustet ein Pferd auf der heimischen Stallgasse, ruft dies meist bei sämtlichen Einstellern ungute Gefühle hervor. Viele haben mindestens eine langwierige Hustenerkrankung mit ihrem Pferd hinter sich. Und sie wissen: Ist die Ursache des Hustens ein viraler Infekt, dauert es oft nicht lang, bis auch die Boxennachbarn husten. 
https://lp.gladiatorplus.com/husten-beim-pferd/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAtP_iBRDGARIsAEWJA8gjHoCDoSeI9ixMPFMe0Wr_OekU88eLjvvY3kNBhjQWft5omkrsU1YaAhkIEALw_wcB

Comment: *Redensarten gehören zu den feststehenden sprachlichen Wendungen (Phraseologismen). Meistens sind es bildhafte Ausdrücke.*
Was ist eine Redensart? Das ist eine ART zu reden: das heisst doch, es ist eine Kunst!  Was einige hier noch nicht begriffen haben: Es ist keine Kunst, Wörter in einem Buch nachzuschlagen, aber es eine Kunst, Begriffe zu erfinden, die bildhaft etwas wiedergeben was man sonst mit vielen Worten nicht so deutlich sagen könnte. Wenn du mal ein Pferd hättest husten hören, würdest du wissen, dass dagegen das Bellen eines Hundes  nur ein klägliches Hüsteln wäre.

Answer (score 1):

Es ist doch recht amüsant, was es alles für Bezeichnungen für hustende Menschen gibt. Mein Favorit einer kurzen Buchrecherche bleibt allerdings:

> Er hustet wie ein schwindsüchtiger Schuster

[Quelle](https://books.google.de/books?id=0TdTAAAAYAAJ&q=%22er+hustet+wie+ein%22&dq=%22er+hustet+wie+ein%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-jZ2MoLHgAhWJ1aYKHUktBCkQ6AEIVjAI)

Deutlich gebräuchtlicher ist allerdings auch im realen Leben der Raucher, die gerne öfter und ausdauernd hustet.

Dementsprechend

> Er hustet wie ein Raucher
>
> oder
>
> Er hustet wie ein alter Kettenraucher

Es gibt allerdings auch die Redewendung "[etwas wie ein Weltmeister tun](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~etwas%20wie%20ein%20Weltmeister%20tun&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)"

Also kann man auch sagen

> Er hustet wie ein Weltmeister

was sozusagen dasselbe bedeutet wie

> Er hustet wie der Teufel.